# C++ programming assignment program termiate with signal 11

Tags: c++

Here is the assignment:  Write a function that takes a char array as an input parameter and reverses the string. The function should use two pointers, front and rear. The front pointer should initially reference the first character in the string, and the rear pointer should initially reference the last character in the string. Reverse the string by swapping the characters referenced by front and rear, then increment front to point to the next character and decrement rear to point to the preceding character, and so on, until the entire string is reversed.

Then, write a main function that takes a string as input from the user and prints the reversed string (using the above function). All input strings will be 100 characters or fewer.

You must use pointers to reverse the array.

If you use dynamic arrays (not required), you must delete all memory allocated to any dynamic arrays before the program ends.

The code is correct. When I do it manually, it can include all characters. Just don't know why I submit to test, it will miss the last character. Here is the error message: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qukiw.png]

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void reverse(char *s);

int main()
{
char str[100] = "";

cout << "Enter string:" << endl;
cin.getline(str,100);

reverse(str);

cout << "The string reversed is:" << endl;
cout << str << endl;

return 0;
}

void reverse(char *s)
{
char *front, *rear, temp;

front = s;
rear = s + strlen(s)-1;
while (front < rear)
{

    temp = *front;
    *front = *rear;
    *rear = temp;

    front++;
    rear--;
}
return;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Why not using `std::sting str("");` instead of `char str[101] = "";`? Would make your life a lot easier Don't tell me please _"but my professor restricts blah blah"_, just skip that course in this case and try to find someone who's actually teaching you c++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: that is all fine and good, but it does not explain why the website shows an error when there is none (anymore). This course seems to be... weird (to put it mildly), but I guess he'll have to live with it. Like some others who had similar problems with a similar course (probably the same). I have seen such output a few times now.

Comment: FWIW, your code runs fine on ideone: https://ideone.com/i20SYm .

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Yes, so I am trying to email the professor to see what is going on.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: One can not always just skip a course. OK, I studied dentistry, not IT, but skipping or not passing a course was not an option. I assume that is similar on many other universities and other faculties. My son (studying civil engineering) can't skip his courses either, although he can more or less pick the semester when he takes them.

Comment: Good. There is something wrong with that evaluation program of theirs.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  char str[100] = " ";
```

^^ initialization is optional

or alternatively...

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
```

this would work too but i dont recommend it , c++ also features other types of casting

```
char* str = new char[100];
```

just another way you could write it, make sure you use the delete operator

```
delete[] str // if you use the new keyword
```

Comment: my question is: When I do it manually, it can include all characters. Just don't know why I submit to test, it will miss the last character.

Comment: the only thing wrong with your code was the buffer overflow issue, which you edited now

Comment: So how can I fix this problem?

Comment: did you notify the instructor? :)